# Insert a range of cells instead of inserting entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
If strSheetDate < strFileNameDate Then
    With WS1
        .Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = strFileNameDate
        .Cells(2, 2).Value = WS3.Cells(2, 2).Value
        .Cells(2, 3).Value = .Cells(1, 11).Value
        .Cells(2, 4).Value = WS3.Cells(3, 2).Value
        .Cells(2, 5).Value = .Cells(1, 13).Value
    End With      
End If
```

and i would like to swap the line:

```
.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

to something where it only moves columns A to E down as I'd like to use the rest of the sheet for more data but don't want it to move down everytime this code is run.

cheers

EDIT **Solution**:

Thanks to the 2 users below I now have the following 2 sets of code, this one is for a simple insert:

```
If strSheetDate < strFileNameDate Then

    With WS1
        .Range("A2:E2").Insert shift:=xlDown
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = strFileNameDate            
        .Cells(2, 2).Value = WS3.Cells(2, 2).Value
        .Cells(2, 3).Value = lngAuthormax               
        .Cells(2, 4).Value = WS3.Cells(3, 2).Value
        .Cells(2, 5).Value = lngConsumermax             
    End With
End If
```

and the second is inserting off of a cell in a range:

```
iRow2 = WS1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngSheetDate2 = WS1.Range("A2:A" & iRow2)

For Each cell In rngSheetDate2
    If cell.Value > strFileNameDate And cell.Offset(1, 0).Value < strFileNameDate Then
        WS1.Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(1, 4)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = strFileNameDate
        cell.Offset(1, 1).Value = WS3.Cells(2, 2).Value
        cell.Offset(1, 2).Value = lngAuthormax
        cell.Offset(1, 3).Value = WS3.Cells(3, 2).Value
        cell.Offset(1, 4).Value = lngConsumermax
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Thank you

Comment: `.Range("A2:E2").Insert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Range(.cells(2, 1), .cells(2, 5)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: with a slight variation you have solved my next question

Comment: Is it related to dynamically reference a range? Anyway, glad it helped.

Comment: yeah needed it to be dynamic as it work through the range, at the moment there is only 5 rows of data but eventually it will have a rolling years worth of data.